# Calling for a new round of applications for a position, when the shortlisted people of the previous round have not yet been even interviewed?

Tags: tenure-track, netherlands

I am invited to an interview for a (STEM) tenure-track position at a prestigious Dutch university. After the deadline, which was months ago, the job advertisement had been removed from their website. But, I have noticed that the job description with a new deadline (in two months) is just added again to their website while my interview is scheduled for the day after tomorrow!

What does that mean to call for a new round of applications for a position, when the shortlisted people of its previous round have not yet been even interviewed?

Comment: We can only speculate but you can ask the committee. Post an answer here after your visit. Good luck!

Comment: I'd say, hope for the best but brace for the worst. The worst is they decided nobody on the short list was suitable. The best is, they decided to hire two people instead of one.

Comment: Might be that they're looking for two people. How do you know that the new ad is for the same position as yours?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Everything, such as the job description title and text as well as its reference number, are the same as the call I  applied for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the noted possibilities in the comments, by [Boba Fit](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/163993/boba-fit):

> I'd say, hope for the best but brace for the worst. The worst is they
> decided nobody on the short list was suitable. The best is, they
> decided to hire two people instead of one

I think it may also resemble the rolling-based applications in North America where universities often do not declare a deadline so they don't have to update it, and while they are processing a batch of applicants of a particular round, the call is still there for new applicants.

Comment: I doubt they would call anyone for an interview if they decided no one was suitable, but they may desire (or even require by some law or policy) more applicants to interview to make an informed decision.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I doubt so. If the number of applicants is a requirement, then they may never reach the threshold they seek, so they can never be able to recruit anyone despite their potential merit and fit. It seems a blocking assumption. Where did you see any requirement like that on the number of applicants in real situations?

Comment: It's common for HR departments to have a requirement like that; the idea would be to avoid 'default' hires, with the assumption that if not enough qualified people applied there was an issue with advertising the position, or to minimize discrimination/appearance of discrimination by only interviewing a single candidate. One example from https://hr.ucf.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/17/Talent-Acquisition-Hiring-Guide-April-2021.pdf "The University requires that in-person on campus interviews be conducted for a minimum of three candidates."

Comment: (I don't know if this is common or not for Dutch universities specifically)

Comment: @BryanKrause: I also think your idea (getting more applicants) is not a legit reason because the deadline of the new job ad is within three months from now. So, they cannot put suitable candidates of the current round on-hold (after their interview) for that long to first get new applicants and then "make an informed decision".

Comment: @Pinton If the law or institutional policy is "you must interview at least 3 candidates", and you only have 2 candidates worth interviewing, what do you do?

Comment: @BryanKrause: Then as long as all such policies are not passed in a round of search, I do not proceed to interviewing people from scratch.

Comment: @Pinton I don't understand how that works to fill a position.

Comment: @BryanKrause: It may not similarly to what you claimed! The only difference is that your interpretation not only does not fill the position but makes the whole thing awkward!

Comment: @Pinton It moves toward getting the job filled, which, for the hiring institution, is most important. They're not going to advertise a job they don't need to fill. If there's a rule about numbers of interviews they can't bypass it. It's a tenure track position so if they eventually want to offer to the first interview they hope they'll still be available. If not, **it doesn't matter because they couldn't hire them anyways without enough interviews**. Anyways, none of this really matters and it's not worth your time to worry about it.